# SQL brackets in where condition needed?

Tags: sql, oracle, logic

```
a AND b or c AND b
```

is equal to

```
(a AND b) or (c AND b)
```

in a SQL where condition right?

Comment: Exactly. AND has higher precedence than OR.

Comment: I'd still use the brackets though, makes your SQL easier to read.

Comment: For given example, both are same. but its always preferred to use brackets